# How does IP Spoofing increase the upload speed?

Tags: ddos, ip-spoofing

I was talking earlier to a script kiddie and claimed that IP spoofing can increase the upload speed in a DDOS attack?! that does not make any sense to me
According to him if your server has an upload speed of 1Gbps IP Spoofing will help you strike a target with a 10Gbps DDOS attack, any explanation? 
Thank you for your answers

Comment: It really theoretically could, if those limits are based on SRCIP. Spoofing SRC you'd have limit*src band. 

Anyway, it seems quite an unreal situation to me, since a real DDOS involves multiple nets with multiple confs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is referring to an attack such as a DNS Amplification Attack. He is not increasing his upstream, but he would be increasing the amount of data being sent to the target.

To make it simple:

- Your friend (1.2.3.4) wants to attack some server (6.7.8.9).
- He spoofs his address to appear to come from the server (6.7.8.9).
- He sends a DNS request to third party server consisting of ~60 bytes.
- The DNS server responds back to the spoofed IP (6.7.8.9) with a ~4000 byte reply.

You can find more details on the details of DNS amplification attacks [here](http://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A).

There are other services that are vulnerable to these types of attack too, including NTP. It also might be worth noting that in my experience, it is very rare that you will find a residential ISP that will forward spoofed packets.

Comment: DNS, NTP, SNMP, etc. are all potential vectors for amplification.